# Delete a segment of text systematically (regex?)

Tags: python, regex

I have text in the following format:

```
        <cast_member billing="top">
            <display_name>Elijah Wood</display_name>
            <character_name>#9 (voice)</character_name>
            <locales>
                <locale name="ko-KR">
                    <display_name>일라이자 우드</display_name>
                </locale>
                <locale name="cmn-Hant">
                    <display_name>伊利亞伍德</display_name>
                </locale>
            </locales>
        </cast_member>
        <cast_member billing="top">
            <display_name>Peter Pan</display_name>
            <character_name>#8 (voice)</character_name>
        </cast_member>
```

How would I delete everything within and inclusive of the `<locales>` tag, when it is present. The input from the above would then look like:

```
        <cast_member billing="top">
            <display_name>Elijah Wood</display_name>
            <character_name>#9 (voice)</character_name>
        </cast_member>
        <cast_member billing="top">
            <display_name>Peter Pan</display_name>
            <character_name>#8 (voice)</character_name>
        </cast_member>
```

Comment: This looks like XML... can you not use an XML parser or something like XSLT to do this instead? Regex is not guaranteed to work for all possible XML, for example: `<elem><elem></elem></elem>`

Comment: Possibly XSLT would be an easier and faster tool than Python here.

Comment: @TheZ is correct, you cannot reliably use a regular expression in this case.  Use an XML parser and remove the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing, using lxml:

```
cast_name = node.xpath("//package/video/cast/cast_member/display_name")
character_name = node.xpath("//package/video/cast/cast_member/character_name")
combined_cast = zip(cast_name, character_name)
cast = [(item1.text, item2.text) for item1, item2 in combined_cast]

[(Elijah Wood,#9 (voice)), (Peter Pan, #8 (voice))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use regex to parse HTML or XML. Use the excellent [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library instead.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job in pure Python without Regex but it might destroy indentation and/or leave blank lines where text has been cut out

```
<cast_member billing="top">
    <display_name>Elijah Wood</display_name>
    <character_name>#9 (voice)</character_name>

</cast_member>
<cast_member billing="top">
    <display_name>Peter Pan</display_name>
    <character_name>#8 (voice)</character_name>
</cast_member>
```

here's the code:

```
with open('data') as f:
    text = f.read()

oTag = "<locales>"
cTag = "</locales>"

newText = ''
p = 0
s = text.find(oTag, p)
while s > -1:
    e = text.find(cTag, s)
    if e == -1:
        # ERROR: no closing tag
        pass
    newText += text[p:s]
    p = e + len(cTag)
    s = text.find(oTag, p)
newText += text[p:]

print newText,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression and the regex replace function

"string".replace(/s/, '') -> "tring"

You could make a regular expression that looks something like this:
/(\s+.+){0,}</locales>/ -> this would match the open and close locales tag, and anything in between.

http://rubular.com/r/WTfo0b2bet to see it in action

myXMLstring.replace(/(\s+.+){0,}</locales>/, '')